# MVVM - Using buttons on View1 to utilize data from SubView1

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

[image]

Concidering this basic GUI diagram of my application, I am using Caliburn.Micro and try to utilize MVVM as best I can;

I have my mainGUI (black) that is an `Conductor`, which has a `ContentControl`
That loads a UserControl when requested from the menu (also ShellViewModel).
This `LabelViewModel` also contains a `ContentControl`, which in turn will display a specific label with settings and input w/e.

I want the buttons on LabelView to be able to print whatever specific label (and settings) that is currently presented on the screen

Would someone be able to tell me how get this working using Caliburn.Micro, or the MVVM implementation?

I am thinking of keeping track of the currently displayed ViewModel in the LabelVM ContentControl, by using properties and then use its properties and sent that to a method in my Print class..

Note that I will have multiple preconfigured labels, probably using Enums to identify them

My quesion got closed earlier because it was opinion based; I can't see where I ask for an opinion, since I ask for a way that Button1 on LabelView executes an action with data from Label1View, while using Caliburn.Micro or even better, MVVM implementations.

Comment: Use a combination of your model and using the event notification service to inform interested view models when state has changed. The model can be referenced by any view model that requires access to information in the model. Your event notification can also reference the model.

Comment: Up until now I only needed the models for my data objects; would you introduce a model here for my 'print label' properties, then on the event of the button, pass that model as a parameter?

Comment: You need models that represent the data behind the application as well as the GUI state. The event notification service is the thing that will allow you to build a decoupled app because it enables things that would otherwise have to be coupled due to needing to share data to be separated and not know anything about each other.